# Jquery transitions running slowly only in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

Mind the placeholdery stuff on the page. http://www.studiobashin.com/ Clicking the "about" button and pressing the <> arrow keys triggers some Jquery:

`$('.carousel').css('transform', 'rotateY(' + YANGLE + 'deg)');`

A CSS change like that is always animated by a transition written in the CSS itself:

`.carousel { transition: transform .4s; }`

The transition runs fine in Firefox, Edge, and Opera. But in Chrome it's laggy. I don't know why.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using - works fine for me (if a bit gaudy)

Comment: Version 69.0.3497.100